# Drupal 8 use display_form mode

Tags: php, forms, drupal, block, drupal-8

I am trying to create a block / page with a form using the [form display mode](https://www.drupal.org/node/2511722)

That looks awesome, even if [permission field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) seems to be something good too for what I want to do, but the challenge is not there...

I want to be able to create a block with a form using form_display mode and of course using the core handler to save it.

I found some sources but I am not quite sure where to hit

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2530086
- The contact source code (create a block)
- The formBlock source code (create a block with a form)

Anyone could give me a hint ?

Comment: From https://www.drupal.org/node/2530086#comment-10962355, I try to use **fiters_entity_type_build**, but I can't reach it (my simple var_dump doesn't display anything). My theme is named **fiters**

Answer (score 5):

All the pieces where in the question.

I will show an example on User Entity, using a module that I created

**Steps will be:**

- Backup !!
- Config a display Form mode in admin interface
- Create a custom module
- Set our formClass for our entity user
- Create a block class
- Add the block to your page
- Enjoy !! (backup again !! never know)

**1 - Config a display Form mode**

Go to this [page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2511722) and follow the steps. It will be really fast, like one field to input... easy !! Please keep the machine_name of the item you will create, mine was **nouvea**. Activate the display modes into 'Config > User parameter > manage fields > advanced settings'

**2 - Create a custom module**

Go to this [page](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/8), not much to do here

- create a folder
- put a module_name.info.yml
- another module_name.module in it, we will use this file after
- done !

**3 - Set our formClass for to our entity user**

As said on this [comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2530086#comment-10962355), you need to declare your form class for your entity User
Add into your module_name.module

```
<?php 


/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_build().
 */ 
function form_display_block_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['user']->setFormClass('nouvea', 'Drupal\user\RegisterForm');
}
```

More details about [hook_entity_type_build()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_type_build/8.2.x)

I am using **'Drupal\user\RegisterForm'** because it is the only form I could have quick and easy access to it without creating one of my own (not sure about the consequences...)

**4 - Create a block class**

We will just copy a class created into [formblock module](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) using user Register form.

I added this class into my 'module folder > src > Plugin > Block'

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\form_display_block\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\Annotation\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilderInterface;

/**
 * Provides a block for the coach registration form.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "formblock_coach_register",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Coach registration form"),
 *   provider = "user",
 *   category = @Translation("Forms")
 * )
 *
 * Note that we set module to contact so that blocks will be disabled correctly
 * when the module is disabled.
 */
class CoachRegisterBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The entity manager
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface.
   */
  protected $entityManager;

  /**
   * The entity form builder
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface.
   */
  protected $entityFormBuilder;

  /**
   * Constructs a new UserRegisterBlock plugin
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin_id for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
   *   The entity manager.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilderInterface $entityFormBuilder
   *   The entity form builder.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, EntityFormBuilderInterface $entityFormBuilder) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->entityFormBuilder = $entityFormBuilder;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity.manager'),
      $container->get('entity.form_builder')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\block\BlockBase::build().
   */
  public function build() {
    $build = array();

    $account = $this->entityManager->getStorage('user') ->create(array());
    $build['form'] = $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($account, 'nouvea');

    return $build;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($account->isAnonymous() && (\Drupal::config('user.settings')->get('register') != USER_REGISTER_ADMINISTRATORS_ONLY))
      ->addCacheContexts(['user.roles'])
      ->addCacheTags(\Drupal::config('user.settings')->getCacheTags());
  }
}
```

I replaced **register** by the name of my new form mode display **nouvea**

In build() function

```
$build['form'] = $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($account, 'register');
```

Replaced by

```
$build['form'] = $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm($account, 'nouvea');
```

**5 - Add the block to your interface**

Now final step is clear your cache (drush cr or interface link) and go to add the created block (you should find the **admin_label**, in my case "Coach registration form") to your page using admin interface.

And hypothetically, it is working great !!